# How to remove shadow from slider backround using Html/Css?

Tags: html, css, slider, background-color

Source:http://www.salefee.com/
I have changed the background of home tab of my above mentioned site to light blue. But I am not able to remove the shadows from extreme left and extreme right side which makes it appear a little bit dark on either side. Is there any way I can make the color appear homogeneous everywehere on home tab?
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow D J. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, proof read before posting and rather include a screenshot image, than a link or webpage, that might break/change in years to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:
Use the following code in your css file:

**Corrected CSS:**

```
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right
{
backround-image:none !important;
}
```

**Why were the shadows appearing:**
The shadows are appearing because your slider has two links or  tags, when I checked their css (bootstrap.min.css), I saw that a background-image was applied to them.

```
<a class="left carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#slideshow-carousel-1">
<a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" href="#slideshow-carousel-1">
```

**Css causing this effect:**

This is the part of your "bootstrap.min.css" code that is causing the shadow effect.

```
.carousel-control.left
{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
}
.carousel-control.right
{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.0001) 100%);
}
```

As you can see the above css is what was causing the shadow effect on your slider. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You could try it out like this.

CSS

```
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}
```

If its not working, try adding important like this

```
background-image: none !important;
```